# Better(faster) way to remove elements from array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove elements from an array based on an array of indices to remove elements from the array.

Here's my code:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const indicesToRemove = [0, 2, 5];

for (let i = indicesToRemove.length; i--;) {
    array.splice(indicesToRemove[i], 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

Result: `[1, 3, 4]`

It seems to be working fine but I wonder if there's a better/faster way to do the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes My question is more about performance rather than how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice is the fastest method

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const indicesToRemove = [0, 2, 5];

for (let index = indicesToRemove.length; index >= 0 ; index--) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

and if you work with a lot of data and make new arrays, such as filter or push, you will have memory problems.

Benchmarking:

```
// setup
const array1 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];
const indicesToRemove1 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];

const array2 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];
const indicesToRemove2 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];

const array3 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];
const indicesToRemove3 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];

const array4 = [...new Array(5000).keys()];
const indicesToRemove4 = new Set([...new Array(5000).keys()]);
```

test 1

```
for (let index = indicesToRemove1.length; index >= 0 ; index--) {
    array1.splice(index, 1);
}
// 3,398 ops/s ±0.71%
// fastest
```

test 2

```
for (let index = indicesToRemove2.length; index--;) {
    array2.splice(index, 1);
}
// 3,377 ops/s ±0.53%
// 0.62% slower
```

test 3

```
const newArray = array4.filter((_,i) => !indicesToRemove4.has(i))
// 3,322 ops/s ±0.5%
// 2.25% slower
```

test 4

```
const newArray = array3.filter((_,i) => !indicesToRemove3.includes(i))
// 22 ops/s ±5.6%
// 99.35% slower
```

Comment: But isn't it dangerous to remove elements in a forward loop? Wouldn't it affect the original array index?

Answer (score 3):

If you can put the array with those elements removed into a *new* variable name, I'd use `filter` to filter out indicies which are in `indiciesToRemove`:

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const indicesToRemove = [0, 2, 5];

const filtered = array.filter((_, i) => !indicesToRemove.includes(i));

console.log(filtered);
```

For less computational complexity, use a Set instead, that way you only have to iterate over the `indiciesToRemove` once, rather than on every iteration:

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const indicesToRemove = new Set([0, 2, 5]);

const filtered = array.filter((_, i) => !indicesToRemove.has(i));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: it's not faster

Comment: If the two arrays are large enough such that performance starts being an issue, the Set solution sure will be faster - it reduces the overall complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`

Comment: Is your solution really faster than mine?

Comment: It seems like mine is a bit faster than yours when I run the benchmark: https://jsben.ch/EyhFO

Comment: Did you guys actually test it?  It's pretty dependent on the size and contents of the array, and the positions of the elements you are removing.  Varies pretty wildly.  Splice ends up being orders of magnitude faster on large sets.

Comment: @ZackLee If you have tiny datasets, performance doesn't matter at all, because the operation will be virtually instantaneous anyway. If you have large datasets, both the `.filter` and the `Set` method will be much faster than `splice`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It seems like mine is even faster with larger datasets like 1,000: https://jsben.ch/qUwwj

Comment: @Zack Lee Your benchmark code is wrong.  One is doing a search every time, and the other is just removing positions without searching.

Comment: @ZackLee You also aren't using the Set method - the Set method is what decreases the computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`. This will have a *huge* positive effect in large datasets.

Comment: One is deleting indexes directly.  The filter does a search every time.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added test with Set and it's still slower

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
arr = array.filter( function(indicesToRemove) {
  return !toRemove.includes(indicesToRemove);
} );

console.log(arr)
```